# Do blindsight and X-ray vision work together?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

This was originally part of [another question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/40998/how-to-get-around-being-unable-to-read-with-blindsight). Blindsight says it requires line of effect to see something, but if I wear a [Ring of X-ray Vision](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/rings.htm#xRayVision) does it allow my blindsight to see through walls within 20 feet?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No. Blindsight requires [Line of Effect](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicOverview/spellDescriptions.htm#lineofEffect), the Ring of X-ray vision grants only Line of Sight. The two special senses do not have a specific, defined interaction, and the X-ray vision doesn't remove the interposing barrier.

To get a supernatural sense to extend through walls, I would try to apply [Burrowing Power](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/psionic/psionicFeats.htm#burrowingPower) to [Touchsight](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/psionic/powers/touchsight.htm).

Answer (score 3):

"Some creatures have blindsight, the extraordinary ability to use a nonvisual sense (or a combination of such senses) to operate effectively without vision." (http://www.d20srd.org/srd/specialAbilities.htm)

So the answer is no, because Blindsight has nothing to do with vision.