# Can a monk “wear” Mage Armor without losing their wisdom bonus to AC?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, monk, armor-class

Can a monk use *mage armor* without losing their wisdom bonus to AC (in 3.5e)?

More generally, can a divine caster wearing a *monk's belt* use *greater luminous armor* without losing their wisdom bonus to AC?  (see [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/71156/optimizing-torso-body-slot-when-restricted-to-light-armor-no-metal-with-high-wi))

Every group I've been in has allowed this (and [forums seem to agree](http://www.enworld.org/forum/showthread.php?175013-Mage-Armor-amp-Monks)), but I want to make sure this is officially legal and not just a house rule.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Yes**

Mage armor (as well as Luminous Armor and it's Greater sibling) aren't armor, they are spells. When they effect you, they are now magic effects. Specifically, they are a force field or an aura of light that gives you some bonuses. They might look like armor, but they aren't.

Since they aren't armor, they won't affect the Monk's AC bonus class ability (of the effect given by a monk's belt that imitates it).