# Does the Invisible Blade's Unfettered Defense feature work if you're under the effect of the Mage Armor spell?

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e, class-feature, armor-class

The Invisible Blade's Unfettered Defense feature (CW 46) says:

> An invisible blade benefits from an increased survival instinct during
>   combat. Because of this sixth sense, he adds 1 point of Intelligence
>   bonus (if any) per invisible blade class level to his Armor Class in
>   addition to any other modifiers he would normally receive. If the
>   invisible blade is caught flat-footed or is otherwise denied his
>   Dexterity modifier to Armor Class, he also loses this bonus.
>   Unfettered defense functions only when an invisible blade is not
>   wearing armor and is armed with one or more daggers, kukris, or
>   punching daggers as his only weapons.

For the purposes of benefiting from Unfettered Defense, are you considered wearing an armor when under Mage Armor spell?

Comment: Welcome! You can take the [tour] as an introduction to the site and check the [help] for further guidance. Good luck and happy gaming!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Yes, Unfettered Defense works with mage armor

Note that [Mage Armor](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/mageArmor.htm) is simply a spell that provides an armor bonus to AC:

> An invisible but tangible field of force surrounds the subject of a mage armor spell, providing a +4 armor bonus to AC.

It is just a spell effect, not actual armor that a character wears. This reasoning is very similar to the one regarding [Mage armor and monks](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/71212/33707).

The bonus to AC that Unfettered Defense provides is also untyped so there are no issues with stacking there.

Answer (score 4):

The spell *magic armor* is a spell that affects a creature, not armor that is being worn. It does not create an object that can be interacted with in any way. So in the most literal meaning of the ability, being under the effect of a *magic armor* spell does not negate its effects.

Since no bonus type is given for the ability, it is an untyped bonus to AC, which also stacks with the armor bonus to AC from *magic armor*.